# How do I create a function that tells me whether a guess has been made before in C Hangman?

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I am working on a project for my C programming assignment where I have to create a simple version of Hangman. The program reads a text file and creates a linked list of all the words inside of the text file. Then chooses a random node from the linked list based on the size requested by the user and give the user a number of lives. After that, it's pretty straight forward. So far I have gotten everything to work perfectly (to my knowledge) except for one thing. I need the game to not allow guessing the same letter multiple times. I tried initializing a guess count that increments by 1 every time a guess is made and an array that stores every guess at the count number in which it was guessed, followed by a for loop which checks if the guess is equal to any of the previous guesses stored in the array. This failed miserably, it was messy and completely dysfunctional only telling me if a guess was repeated when it wanted to. I am at a loss right now. Any help is greatly appreciated, please, and thank you!
My code is a bit messy but the comments should make it a little more clear for you.

[Link to the words.txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoiYHSFfzsQ_hGtPhzqSu8bCABV0Nawc/view?usp=sharing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int nodeNum, chances, misses, score, corrGuess, wordLen = 0, countGs = 0;
char* secret;
char incorrGuess[50], guess, dashes[15], prevGuess[50];



/*Node of linked list*/
typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *start = NULL;
node *current;

/*Appending nodes to linked list*/
void add(char *line) {

    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = strdup(line);
    temp->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }
}

/*read text file*/
void readfile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[512];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        add(buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

/*Set initial dashes string*/
void setInitDash(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < strlen(secret)-1; i++){
        dashes[i] = '-';
    }
}

/*Generate random number between 0 and 2999*/
void randNum(int lower, int upper)
{
    srand(time(0));
    nodeNum = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;

}

/*Choose random node based on random number generated and length given by user*/
void chooseRand(struct node* start, int i)
{

    node* p;
    int n;
    p = start;
    for(n = 0; n != nodeNum; n++)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    while(strlen(p->data) != i + 1){
        p = p->next;
    }
    if(p->data == NULL){
        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nProgram has run out of words, please restart later");
        exit(0);
    }
    secret = p->data;
    setInitDash();
}

/*Check guess for correct guess*/
void checkGuess(){

    int i, j = strlen(secret) - 1;
    for(i = 0; i != j; i++){
        if(secret[i] == guess) {
            dashes[i] = guess;
            score++;
            corrGuess++;
        }
    }
}

/*Check if score changes*/
void checkScore(){
    if(score == 0){
        misses++;
        chances--;
        incorrGuess[misses] = guess;
    }
    else{
        score = 0;
    }
    printf("%s", dashes);
}






/*Print current board*/
void printBoard(){
    printf("__________________________________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n\nCurrent Word: ");
    checkGuess();
    checkScore();
    printf("   Chances: %d Incorrect Guesses: ", chances);
    for(int i = 0; i <= misses; i++)
        printf("%c", incorrGuess[i]);
    printf("\nPlease enter your guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);
    printf("\n__________________________________________________________________\n");
}

/*Function for if player wins*/
void winCase(){
    printf("\n\n\n\n\nGood Job! You have guessed the word correctly. It was %s Restart the program to play again!", secret);
}

/*Function for if player loses*/
void loseCase(){
    printf("\n\n\n\n\nUnfortunately, you have run out of chances. The word to guess was %s.", secret);
}



int main(){
    score = 0;
    corrGuess = 0;
    int stillPlaying = 1;

    printf("Hello User, Welcome to Hangman\nPlease enter word length then number of chances: ");     /*Welcome Message*/
    scanf("%d %d", &wordLen, &chances);

    readfile("words.txt"); /*Readfile and choose random word*/
    randNum(0, 2999);
    chooseRand(start, wordLen);
    printf("%s", secret);   /*Print secret word for easy testing*/
    printf("__________________________________________________________________\n");     /*Print first iteration of the board*/
    printf("\n\nCurrent Word: %s", dashes);
    printf("   Chances: %d Incorrect Guesses: %s", chances, incorrGuess);
    printf("\nPlease enter your guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);
    printf("\n__________________________________________________________________\n");
    while(stillPlaying == 1){       /*While loop to print board until win or lose case is true*/
        printBoard();
        if(corrGuess == strlen(secret) - 2){
            stillPlaying = 2;
        }
        else if(chances == 0){
            stillPlaying = 0;
        }
    }
    if(stillPlaying == 0){
        loseCase();
    }
    else if(stillPlaying == 2){
        winCase();
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why tag the question with "linked list"? guesses in Hangman are from a limited alphabet (36 letters / numbers?)... wouldn't an boolean array or bitmap be better?

Comment: @Myst: There doesn't seem to be enough logic here. Yes I'm complaining that something with way too much code is missing something, but I can't make progress. Giving up.

Comment: I had to use a linked list for my assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd make an array like this `bool guessed[256];` (`char` has 256 possible values), and make sure all values are 0. Then, when a guess is made, set `guessed[guessedChar]` to 1. And to check if it's guessed you'd use `if (guessed[charToCheckIfGuessed]) { ... }`. I don't see why you're trying to use a linked list, you're really just giving yourself a harder time than you need to.

Not only is this faster than a for loop, but to my understanding it should work just fine.

Comment: Like I said, I have to because it's a requirement in my assignment

Comment: @OmarAbzd Be that as it may, I think you should try this